# Spring AOP with different args

Tags: spring, aop

My advice method accepts an object parameter `Foo`, but the point cut method also accepts an object parameter `Bar`.

In the point cut method, there are two variables that are part of the Foo object needed to be passed into advice method.

How can I implement this? Thanks in advance.

pointcut method:

```
aPointCutMethod(Bar bar){

    // These two params needed to be used to construct Foo object and pass it to the   advice method
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
}
```

Foo object:

```
Class Foo {
    String attr1;
    String attr2;
}
```

advice method:

```
anAdviceMethod(Foo foo);
```

Comment: Show it with examples so we can visualize more easily, please.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Code added.

Comment: I just fixed some typos like the hilarious "pointCunt". But still the content of your question is unclear. Please improve your code example and/or explain clearer what you want to do: Where do the String parameters come from? Are they local variables? If so, where? What do you mean by "pointcut method"? Is it a method intercepted by a pointcut or really a pointcut? I would like to see the pointcut syntax, the advice and some code which is to be intercepted by the pointcut/advice combo.